# Changes In Access Database To Only Be Present in New Records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in access that has a series of questions. Each question has a frame with three radio buttons with each radio button designating a different selection (for ease 1, 2, 3). I have added a question to this form and would like for some way to designate all of the records prior to the change to be exempt from this field. I thought I could set the value of this field in the previous records to -1 to signify that they are exempt. But now I don't know how to essentially disable this question on the previous records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how well I understand your description, by my hunch is the form's current event could be useful here.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.ControlName.Enabled = Not Me.indicator_field = -1
End Sub
```

If `ControlName` should be `Enabled` for new records, you can use the Nz`()` function to handle the initial Null.

```
Me.ControlName.Enabled = Not Nz(Me.indicator_field, 0) = -1
```

You could also manage `ControlName` 's `Locked` property instead of or in addition to `Enabled`.  The combinations alter the control's appearance in different ways.  See which you prefer.

There may be other details I overlooked, but hopefully that gives you a useful starting point.

If your form contains text boxes in a sequence such as Text1, Text2, ... Textn, you can use a `For` loop to do something with each of them ... enable/disable or whatever ... I'll use `Debug.Print` because it's easy for me.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim strCtl As String
For i = 1 To 10
    strCtl = "Text" & CStr(i)
    Debug.Print Me.Controls(strCtl).Name
Next i
```

The key there is you can use your string variable to refer to a specific member of the form's `Controls` collection.  Then do what you need with it, instead of printing its `.Name` property.

Comment: Do you know if there is an easy way to loop through elements on a screen to do this for multiple fields of the same name but numerically ordered?

Comment: What do you mean by numerically ordered: Text1; Text2; Text3; etc?

Comment: That is what I mean precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the NewRecord property:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
     If Me.NewRecord = True
        Then Me.MyControl.Enabled = True
     Else
        Then Me.MyControl.Enabled = False
     End If
End Sub
```

Or using your new field, you can say:

```
If Me.MyField = -1
    Then Me.MyControl.Enabled = False
 Else
    Then Me.MyControl.Enabled = True
 End If
```

It is nearly always a good idea to include a datetime of creation in MS Access tables.

Comment: These records get revisited several times. So there will be a point when it is not a new record and will be opened back up again.